# Fast tap on TextView clearing random portion of my Custom View

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am  using one  40 miliseconds  timer  and am plotting graph with this speed. (In each  40 milisecsnds of onDraw() call , it is plotting 5  points). 
but  on the layout same time when I am  taping on one TextView, it is clearing random portion of Custom View.

So my question Is

1. Is it related with cache Drawing. ?
2. I tried with setDrawingcacheEnabled(true);  but this also is not working.

   Any idea  ?

   This is my onDraw()

   ```
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
   {    
       super.onDraw(canvas);
          //setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
         //canvas.drawBitmap(bBitMap,0,0,null);
         drawStuff(canvas);
     }
   ```

   My cache  memory Size is 256k and my screen resulotion  is 800x480